# If Statement in linked list not working as expected

Tags: c, if-statement, struct, linked-list

So currently i have an `if` statement in the `GetNth` function that im trying to test. but when i inserted a `printf` function, it made me notice that it goes through the `if` statement even if the condition is not met, however, when i remove the `printf` statement the program works flawlessly. any explanation would be appreciated.

Notice! This is not my code, im trying to study linked lists and was changing the code around trying to learn!

The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* Link list node */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head
 of a list and an int, push a new node on the front
 of the list. */
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* allocate node */
    struct node* new_node =
    (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    /* put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

/* Takes head pointer of the linked list and index
 as arguments and return data at index*/
int GetNth(struct node* head, int index)
{
    struct node* current = head;
    int count = 0; /* the index of the node we're currently
                    looking at */
    int a;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (count == index)
            return(current->data);
            a = current->data;
            printf("\n Testing If in linked list, should bring same desired value which is 4 %d \n ",a);
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }

    /* if we get to this line, the caller was asking
     for a non-existent element so we assert fail */
    assert(0);
}

/* Drier program to test above function*/
int main()
{
    /* Start with the empty list */
    struct node* head = NULL;

    /* Use push() to construct below list
     1->12->1->4->1  */
    push(&head, 1);
    push(&head, 4);
    push(&head, 1);
    push(&head, 12);
    push(&head, 1);
    if (head != NULL)
    {

    }
    /* Check the count function */
    printf("Element at index 3 is %d", GetNth(head, 3));
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing braces.

That's why I am a defender of "Always add braces".

Edit for "solution".

The current code is:

```
while (current != NULL)
{
    if (count == index)
        return(current->data);
        a = current->data;
        printf("\n Testing If in linked list, should bring same desired value which is 4 %d \n ",a);
    count++;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Without braces, an if statement only applies to the next instruction, that is `return(current->data);`

If you want to include multiple instructions into an if block, you must create a block, with braces.

```
if (count == index)
{
        return(current->data);
        a = current->data;
        printf("\n Testing If in linked list, should bring same desired value which is 4 %d \n ",a);
}
```

However, you begin with a return instruction so the following 2 lines will never be executed.

Reorder your instructions to print before the return.

```
if (count == index)
{
     a = current->data;
     printf("\n Testing If in linked list, should bring same desired value which is 4 %d \n ",a);
     return(current->data);
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate your answer with solution example.

Comment: Added an elaborated answer.

Comment: I agree with the diagnosis.  I disagree with the remedy — my preferred remedy is to think, remembering that C is not Python.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not going into `if statement` even if condition is false.

`If` statement considers only immediate next statement after the if statement if there is no curly braces.

```
if (count == index)
            return(current->data);
```

it considers only return statement if statement is true.

If statement is false it goes to the next statement after the `;`  
i.e

```
 a = current->data;
            printf("\n Testing If in linked list, should bring same desired value which is 4 %d \n ",a);
```

Thats the reason you are feeling that if statement is not working.

If you need to use `printf` inside if loop you need to used syntax for multiple statements inside if loop. i.e via curly braces

```
if (condition)
{
   //statement
   //statement
}
```